# Does WP read itself?

Tags: server

I was looking at my server logs and I saw something strange. Every day, sometimes multiple times a day, I see a sequence of hits like this:

> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:04:36:09 -0800] "GET /blogs/about/ HTTP/1.0" 200 18075 "-" "WordPress/3.5; [my blog URL]"
>
> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:04:36:11 -0800] "GET /blogs/3/a-star-is-born/ HTTP/1.0" 200 13301 "-" "WordPress/3.5; [my
>   blog URL]"
>
> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:04:36:12 -0800] "GET /blogs/8/107655531126398381/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9462 "-" "WordPress/3.5;
>   [my blog URL]"
>
> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:04:36:14 -0800] "GET /blogs/9/107659020500242493/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9715 "-" "WordPress/3.5;
>   [my blog URL]"
>
> ...
>
> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:11:38:52 -0800] "GET /blogs/17493/bonus/ HTTP/1.0" 200 13671 "-" "WordPress/3.5; [my blog
>   URL]"
>
> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:11:38:53 -0800] "GET /blogs/17496/monday-cat-blogging-367/ HTTP/1.0" 200 10019 "-"
>   "WordPress/3.5; [my blog URL]"
>
> 67.210.126.90 - - [17/Dec/2012:11:38:55 -0800] "GET /blogs/17497/start-your-ipods-363/ HTTP/1.0" 200 10418 "-"
>   "WordPress/3.5; [my blog URL]"

That is, something on 67.210.126.90 (which is nasa.lunarpages.com, the server where the blog is hosted) is fetching every single blog post I've ever made, in order. I assume Wordpress is doing this, but I've searched for hours and couldn't find any info about why Wordpress would do that (or even if Wordpress does that at all). It doesn't make a lot of sense that Wordpress would do that - it can just read the posts from the DB, after all, it doesn't need to render them. But as far as I know, I'm not running anything else on my account.

But, if it's not Wordpress, I'm truly stumped. I have no idea what else on the hosting server would be doing a GET on all pages.

Anyone ever seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

The user agent you are seeing in logs is consistent with defaults of WordPress HTTP API:

```
'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . get_bloginfo( 'url' )
```

You can verify that requests are coming from your WordPress installation by using [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin's HTTP logging module.

But from this information it is impossible to say *why* these requests are happening. It might be intended or not, as well as coming from core or extension (plugin/theme).